# Confusing ReaderT definition

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, reader-monad

As an exercise I've been reimplementing some common monads and their corresponding transformers; here are some of the types I've defined:

```
newtype Writer  w   a = Writer  { runWriter  :: (w, a) }
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { runWriterT :: m (Writer w a) }

newtype Maybe    a = Just a | Nothing
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

As I get it a transformer "wraps" a monad in an outer monad `m`; following this intuition I tried defining the `ReaderT` transformer in a similar way as:

```
newtype Reader  r   a = Reader  { runReader  :: r -> a }
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: m (Reader r a) }
```

However, I got stuck implementing its monad instance. By looking at the library definition of `ReaderT` I see that it is defined as

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

Aside from the fact that it does not use `Reader` (that can be defined in terms of `ReaderT`), why is it defined as `r -> m a` and not `m (r -> a)`? I thought it should wrap the inner `Reader` (i.e. `r -> a`) with the outer monad `m` obtaining `m (r -> a)` and not `r -> m a`

Comment: "I tried it this way and it didn't work, why is it done a different way?" seems like it pretty much answers itself.

Comment: Monad, in general, do not compose. If `m` and `n` are monads, `m (n -)` is not necessarily one. If they did compose, we would not need "monad transformers". By comparison, functors compose, and there is no such a thing like "functor transformers".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m (r -> a)` means that you:

1. First perform some action in the monad, and then,
2. After the action is **complete**, perform a pure calculation on the reader value.

But you need to be able to use `ask`:

```hs
ask :: Monad m => ReaderT r m r
```

With `ask`, you can:

1. First read the value,
2. Then perform some monadic action, acting on the value.

That is why `r -> m a` makes sense and `m (r -> a)` does not make sense.

If it helps, think of this as “symmetrical” with the writer monad. With the writer monad, the monad is on the outside, and the result is on the inside. With the reader monad, the input is on the outside, and the monad is on the inside. This kind of symmetry shows up a lot.

Comment: Why is `ask` the counterexample? What is wrong with `ask = ReaderT (pure id)`

Comment: It's probably wrong to ask because without a valid `Monad` instance it cannot be a monad transformer, but `ask` doesn't seem why

Comment: @Iceland_jack: implement -> use